# refresh for user specific views in adaptive card are not triggering Invoke

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Currently trying to implement a User Specific View for adaptive Cards.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/universal-action-model#refresh-mechanism) shows how to auto refresh an adaptive Card and also how to deal with the invoke. I implemented my BotMessageActivity and whenever I write something to the bot response with a card as a result:

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(cardAttachment), cancellationToken);
```

So far so good. I receive the Card but somehow my I InvokeActivity is not getting triggered:

```
protected override async Task<InvokeResponse> OnInvokeActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken){...}
```

My main goal is to change the title and value of the URL at the end.

This is how my adaptive Card looks like:

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.4",
"refresh": {
    "action": {
        "type": "Action.Execute",
        "title": "Refresh",
        "verb": "refresh",
        "data": {
            "CreatedBy": "test"
        }
    },
    "userIds": [
        "999111999111999111"
    ]
},
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "auto",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "url": "URL"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "auto",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "url": "URL"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "TestText",
                            "wrap": true,
                            "weight": "Bolder"
                        },
                        {
                            "color": "default",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "left",
                            "isSubtle": false,
                            "size": "medium",
                            "weight": "default",
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "TestText",
                            "wrap": true,
                            "spacing": "medium"
                        }
                    ],
                    "verticalContentAlignment": "center"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "FactSet",
                            "facts": [
                                {
                                    "title": "TestId",
                                    "value": "JustAnId"
                                },
                                {
                                    "title": "AnyData",
                                    "value": "AnyTest"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "spacing": "medium"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                    "title": "ButtonA",
                    "url": "UrlA"
                }
            ],
            "spacing": "medium"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please check these samples - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/universal-actions-for-adaptive-cards/work-with-universal-actions-for-adaptive-cards,,  https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-adaptivecards-user-specific-views/csharp,, https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-sequential-flow-adaptive-cards/csharp

Comment: I checked the samples already. I have the refresh in my Card and as soon I add this I should be able to get into the BotInvoke method. 

I tried to check this in debug mode. But somehow the "refresh" does not run the BotInvoke

Comment: We setup the bot-adaptivecards-user-specific-views sample at our end and bot is hitting OnInvokeActivityAsync properly. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/2740a48148d3dc12eb8d545b21f2e28de856ea84/samples/bot-adaptivecards-user-specific-views/csharp/Microsoft.Teams.Samples.UserSpecificViews/Bot/BotActivityHandler.cs#L41 
We tested it in Teams web client. Could you please share more details so that we can try and reproduce the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I initially assumed that the MRI (Member Resource Identifier) was identical to the User Object ID available in the Azure Portal. I thought I could simply use the User Object ID for testing purposes. However, I discovered that this was not the case; the MRI and User Object ID are indeed different entities. Once I input the correct MRI value, the bot successfully executed the Invoke method.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I could simply use the User Object ID for testing purposes and that the User Object ID is the same Value as the MRI. However, I discovered that this was not the case; the MRI and User Object ID are indeed different entities.

After entering the right MRI value, the Bot was able to call the Invoke method.